# Puppeteer $eval() with parent element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

`page.$eval()` runs `document.querySelector`, but I want to use it with parent element.
There is `element.querySelector` but there isn't `element.$eval()` in puppeteer, and also I cannot manually put parent inside selector because I am iterating arrays of elements found by `page.$$eval()`.
I have to use puppeteer screenshot, so `element.evaluate(el => el.querySelector())` won't work too.

Comment: Sorry, can you show a [mcve] and HTML showing what you're trying to do/select/screenshot? `evaluate()` can do basically anything you can do in a browser, e.g. `element.evaluate(el => el.parentNode.querySelector(...))` if that's what you're looking for, although there may be a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.